# can I use the license keys from a Microsoft office family pack between friends not in the same household?

Tags: ms-office

The note on the site for this says its for 3 Macs in the same household. A friend and I want to split the cost of the family pack. We don't live in the same household. I had a  chat on the MS Office site with a representative and he said it would be breaking the license agreement to split the license keys between friends. Does anyone know how or if this is enforced?

Comment: As per the [FAQ], questions on this site should not be about obtaining or using pirated software.

Answer (score 2):

A velociraptor will jump out of your DVD drive.

Since you are only licensed to use the software in one single household, one of the two of you will be using pirated software, and since you are "splitting the costs", the other one will be selling pirated software.